# Add new layout to magento for output category

Tags: magento, layout

I have custom layout for category.

---

```
<CATEGORY_8>
       <reference name="root">
           <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/category_8.phtml</template></action>
       </reference>
       <reference name="left">
           <block type="catalog/category_view" name="catalog.leftnav.within" before="-" template="catalog/layer/within.phtml   "/>
       </reference>
       <reference name="category.products">
           <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/category/8/view.phtml</template></action>
       </reference>
       <reference name="catalog.leftnav">
           <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/layer/view_8.phtml</template></action>
       </reference>
       <reference name="product_list">
           <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/list_8.phtml</template></action>
       </reference>
   </CATEGORY_8>
```

---

I want create new layout and I want apply this layout for category.
I created new layout

```
<page_new_new module="page" translate="label">
<label>Layout new</label>
<template>page/category_8.phtml</template>
<layout_handle>page_new_new</layout_handle>
</page_new_new>
```

How I can setup templates for this layout?

I don't want using "Custom Layout Update" field inside admin.
I want use only "Page Layout" field?

Comment: where are you adding this layout code, int the cms or in a layout xml file?

Answer (score 0):

I would insert the layout xml block (your first code part with CATEGORY_8) into `design/frontend/*/*/layout/page.xml` (your actual frontend design folder, most possibly default/default) and create an extension with a simple `config.xml`, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <global>  
    <page>
      <layouts>
        <page_new_new module="page" translate="label">
        <label>Layout new</label>
        <template>page/category_8.phtml</template>
        <layout_handle>page_new_new</layout_handle>
        </page_new_new>
      </layouts>
    </page>
  </global>
</config>
```

To create an extension just create the folder structure in your `app/code/local` directory:

```
 YourCompanyName/ModuleNameYouLike/etc
```

and put this [config.xml] in, you will also need an xml file in `app/etc/modules` directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>     
    <YourCompanyName_ModuleNameYouLike>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <depends>
        <Mage_Page />
      </depends>
    </YourCompanyName_ModuleNameYouLike>
  </modules>
</config>
```

After refreshing configuration and layout cache you will see `Layout new` for pages from the `Page layout` dropdown.